# Installing .deb files on Debian LXDE

Tags: debian, lxde

I just installed Debian LXDE for the first time and I can't seem to find a way to simply install .deb packages like chrome, for instance. I tried gdebi and dpkg but got nowhere up until now. What's the secret here?

Comment: You know how Debian software repositories work, and package managers like synaptic, apt, etc? I had no idea when I first tried linux, was trying to find & download files from websites like a sucker ;-) Chrome is one you do have to download, but Chromium is in most distribution's repositories

Answer (score 1):

Download the .deb. Use your Package Manager to look at the .deb you have downloaded. RIGHT click on the .deb. Choose "Open with Gdebi". Let Gdebi run.

Comment: Actually LXDE is just a desktop environment, not it's own distribution and not based on [L]Ubuntu (see [Debian's wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LXDE) &/or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE)). Debian does have a live LXDE version, so if anything a Debian tag could help

Comment: Sorry. Confused it with LXLE, again! Amended post.

Comment: A LOT of the names really are too similar. Anyway, without more info from the OP it's hard to tell if they got gdebi to open the right file, or if their file is even for debian or the right architecture, but still +1

Answer (score 1):

It's not available in the Debian Sources, one has to download the binary from Google directly, install it - the Installer will place the appropriate download source in '/etc/apt/sources.list.d' for the upgrade cycle.